# How to convert "group by", "having" query from mysql to mongodb in phalcon

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, phalcon

I'm trying to convert query from mysql to mongodb

In MySql i use:

```
$top_orders = Orders::find(array(
                    "columns" =>"pro_id",
                    "group"=>"pro_id",
                    "having"=>"count(pro_id) > 100",
                    "order"=>"RAND()",
                    "limit"=>5
                )
            );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really a direct correlation to this, but the closest you can get is by implementing the aggregate() method from [Collection](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Collection.html).

```php
$top_orders = Orders::aggregate(array(
   array( '$group' => array( 
       '_id' => '$pro_id',
       'count' => array( '$sum' => 1 )
   )),
   array( '$match' => array( 
       'count' => array( '$gt' => 100 )
   )),
   array( '$sort' => array( 'count' => -1 ) ),
   array( '$limit' => 5 )
));
```

As you can see, the missing part there is your `RAND()` function, where there is no direct alternate in MongoDB aggregation queries to generate such a random number in an aggregation pipeline.

You can however do what I do for the example here and sort by something you have present, such as tge "count" total. You can also use [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to alter fields if you think you need specific names on output. The [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline requires a "key" as `_id` so it's usually in best performance considerations to just leave that alone.

So the basic steps if you can live with it are [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and [**`$limit`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/). These are all aggregation pipeline stages and that is the general way that MongoDB does it as a SQL like DSL does not translate well to anything implemented on `find()`.